# Fetching all Receive payment records from quckbooks database?

Tags: php, quickbooks

Working on a quickbooks api project in php. I created a request query for getting all receive payment records from quickbooks database. But the webconnector is giving error like Invalid xml. can u pls help me with the request and response query??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently worked on this same project, so I can post complete code for receive payment records.

I think you are using quickbooks php api downloaded from consolibyte.

So in query request copy function like this :-

```
 function _quickbooks_receivepayment_query_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
```

{

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
    <QBXML>
        <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <ReceivePaymentQueryRq>
        <IncludeLineItems>true</IncludeLineItems>
            </ReceivePaymentQueryRq>    
        </QBXMLMsgsRq>
    </QBXML>';

return $xml;
```

}